# CiviRules - triggers, but no mails sent

Tags: civirules

Similar to [CiviRules triggers, but fails to send email](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35649/civirules-triggers-but-fails-to-send-email),
but I've not seen a resolution there. For the past ~year, have had CiviRules sending my DRIP email campaign, along with a couple of tag setting functions.

(techie enough to be dangerous... I can get in to things, but...)

Recently, (not sure exactly when) I noticed that it wasn't sending the emails, though, it was processing other things in the actions. Emails do send no problem - manually.

I didn't know about CiviRules logging, so just loaded it, but don't know where the logs might show up. I added another user, it triggered, but no emails, and no errors - at least not seen in Administer> Administration Console> View Log.

From above post, I saw about civicrm_queue_item table. There are a number of items there from the past ~2 months, but I don't know how to interpret.

Cron is running, including process civirules and process delayed civirule actions (both always, with no errors).

I just saw another question with problem with delays, so I changed the delay on my first email from 1minute - to no delay. Created user, with the trigger tag. It sent the email! Now, will it send the rest? (2, 4, 6... day delays on them.

Running:
WordPress 5.5
CiviCRM 5.27.3
CiviRules 2.16
Email API 1.19

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions/hints...
..clark

Comment: Updated to 5.28.2 this morning, and re-triggered. This time email was sent! Not sure what was happening/is happening. Will continue to monitor, and if I figure anything out - I'll update here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the root cause of the failure, but, installing the 5.28.2 seems to have fixed the issue.